# Selecting a non-contiguous submatrix in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am trying to select a submatrix in [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp) with non-contiguous slices. The equivalent R code is

```
> xx = matrix(0,nrow=10,ncol=8)
> xx[,c(1,3,4)]
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0
 [8,]    0    0    0
 [9,]    0    0    0
[10,]    0    0    0
```

In Rcpp, I am tried to do

```
Rcpp::NumericMatrix xx(10,8);
Rcpp::NumericMatrix aa = xx(Rcpp::Range(0,9), Rcpp::NumericVector::create(1,3,4));
```

However, this gives

```
error: no match for call to '(Rcpp::NumericMatrix) (Rcpp::Range, Rcpp::Vector<14>)'
/opt/local/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Matrix.h:126: note: candidates are: typename Rcpp::Vector<RTYPE>::Proxy Rcpp::Matrix<RTYPE>::operator()(const size_t&, const size_t&) [with int RTYPE = 14]
/opt/local/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Matrix.h:132: note:                 typename Rcpp::Vector<RTYPE>::Proxy Rcpp::Matrix<RTYPE>::operator()(const size_t&, const size_t&) const [with int RTYPE = 14]
/opt/local/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Matrix.h:142: note:                 Rcpp::MatrixRow<RTYPE> Rcpp::Matrix<RTYPE>::operator()(int, Rcpp::internal::NamedPlaceHolder) [with int RTYPE = 14]
/opt/local/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Matrix.h:146: note:                 Rcpp::MatrixColumn<RTYPE> Rcpp::Matrix<RTYPE>::operator()(Rcpp::internal::NamedPlaceHolder, int) [with int RTYPE = 14]
/opt/local/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Matrix.h:150: note:                 Rcpp::SubMatrix<RTYPE> Rcpp::Matrix<RTYPE>::operator()(const Rcpp::Range&, const Rcpp::Range&) [with int RTYPE = 14]
/opt/local/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Matrix.h:154: note:                 Rcpp::SubMatrix<RTYPE> Rcpp::Matrix<RTYPE>::operator()(Rcpp::internal::NamedPlaceHolder, const Rcpp::Range&) [with int RTYPE = 14]
/opt/local/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Matrix.h:158: note:                 Rcpp::SubMatrix<RTYPE> Rcpp::Matrix<RTYPE>::operator()(const Rcpp::Range&, Rcpp::internal::NamedPlaceHolder) [with int RTYPE = 14]
```

Is this possible in Rcpp?

Comment: I still think rcpp-devel is a better place for questions like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I've done it:

```
library(inline)

testSlice = cxxfunction(signature(r_mat='int', r_cols='int'), body = 
'
NumericMatrix mat (r_mat);
NumericVector cols (r_cols);

NumericMatrix matslice (mat.nrow(), cols.size());

for (int i=0; i<cols.size(); i++) {
  matslice(_,i) = mat(_, cols(i)-1);
}

return(matslice);
'
, plugin='Rcpp')
```

```
> xx = matrix(sample(10, 10*10, replace=T), nrow=10)
> xx
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    6    7    9    8    2    6    1    8   10     8
 [2,]    5    6    9    5    1    5    2    7   10     3
 [3,]    9    5    1   10    8   10   10    1    2     7
 [4,]    2    7    1    4    5    1    8    2   10     9
 [5,]    6    6    9    8    3    1    2   10    2     1
 [6,]    4    6    7    9    7    5    4    7   10    10
 [7,]   10   10    8    8   10    7   10    4    6     3
 [8,]    6    3   10    6    3    2    5    4    1    10
 [9,]    8    7    2    7    9    7    7    8    3    10
[10,]    5    4    5    4    4    8   10    1    5     4

> testSlice(xx, c(2,5,6))
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    7    2    6
 [2,]    6    1    5
 [3,]    5    8   10
 [4,]    7    5    1
 [5,]    6    3    1
 [6,]    6    7    5
 [7,]   10   10    7
 [8,]    3    3    2
 [9,]    7    9    7
[10,]    4    4    8
```

Comment: That's pretty nice.  RcppArmadillo has support for slices through Armadillo's slices.

Comment: Great! I've been getting more and more into Rcpp, Dirk. It is really fantastic. So far I've just been using it to hack together little numerical codes to offload from R, but by just learning a bit I can tell the potential is huge. Many thanks! I'll have to check into RcppArmadillo when I need to do some real matrix work...it sounds really useful too.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, from http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat, I don't see a method for non-contiguous slices, just things like `X.submat( span(first_row, last_row), span(first_col, last_col) )` and `X.elem( vector_of_indices )`.

Comment: Addedum August 2013: Armadillo can subset from non-contiguous matrices, see [this Rcpp Gallery article](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/armadillo-subsetting/) for an example.

Answer (score 6):

The help file for NumericMatrix: http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/html/classMatrix.html

It shows that there are no methods that take a Range and a NumericVector, only two Ranges or an "_" and a range... So there is no direct way of selecting non-contiguous slices...

Comment: I second that +1 and am actually speechless.  Someone reads docs?  Wow.  Maybe there was a reason we wrote them....

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel - Well, after listening to your presentation yesterday, I kind of felt inspired to read a little :-)

Comment: There are methods mixing a "_" with an int or Range. Shouldn't there be methods for mixing int and Range as well, for the sake of completeness?

Comment: @highBandWidth - I was expecting that too. A workaround is `Range(2,2)`... @DirkEddelbuettel - maybe an auto-convert from `int` to `Range` would do the trick?

Comment: Patches welcome. Feel free to come over to rcpp-devel to discuss.

Answer (score 0):

You can just to this, no? Probably you will have to adjust the argument and return type

```
mat submat_cols(mat X, uvec idx) {
    mat y = X.cols(idx);
    return y;
}
```

The question is also related to the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038256/subset-of-a-rcpp-matrix-that-matches-a-logical-statement/13731827#13731827). I just posted three solutions with benchmark over there. It's about subsetting a matrix based on a logical vector though. But it's a similar problem and 
`xx[,c(1:8) %in% c(1,3,4)]` instead of `xx[,c(1,3,4)]` should produce the same result. In any case, it would be really great to have sugar solutions for these things.