# Rcpp: extract subset of matrix using indexmatrix

Tags: r, performance, subset, default-value, rcpp

I have a question about subsetting from a matrix to a vector. The user has the possibility to explicitly give the indexmatrix (which is a matrix of the same size as M, with 0 if the entry is not wanted, and 1 if the entry has to be extracted). If the indexmatrix is provided, then we just subset it, and if the indexmatrix is not provided (indexmatrix = NULL), then we build it using type1 (which takes true or false). Only two types of indexmatrices are possible.

I used the subsetting technique provided in
[Subset of a Rcpp Matrix that matches a logical statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038256/subset-of-a-rcpp-matrix-that-matches-a-logical-statement)

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::colvec extractElementsRcpp(arma::mat M, 
         Rcpp::Nullable<Rcpp::NumericMatrix> indexmatrix = R_NilValue,
         bool type1 = false) {

  unsigned int D = M.n_rows;  // dimension of the data
  arma::mat indmatrix(D, D);  // initialize indexmatrix

  if (indexmatrix.isNotNull()) {
     // copy indexmatrix to numericmatrix
     Rcpp::NumericMatrix indexmatrixt(indexmatrix);
     // make indexmatrix into arma matrix indmatrix  
     indmatrix = Rcpp::as<arma::mat>(indexmatrixt);  
  } //else {
    // get indexmatrix
 //   Rcpp::NumericMatrix indexmatrixt = getindexmatrix(D, type1)["indexmatrix"]; 
 //   // make indexmatrix into arma matrix
 //   indmatrix = Rcpp::as<arma::mat>(indexmatrixt);  
 // }

  arma::colvec unM = M.elem(find(indmatrix == 1)); // extract wanted elements

  return(unM);
}
```

It works, great! However, the speed is not what I was hoping for. Whenever the indexmatrix is provided, the C++ code is slower than the normal R code, while I was aiming for a nice improvement in speed. I have the feeling I'm copying the matrices around too much. But I am new to C++ and did not find a way to avoid it yet.

The speed comparison is as follows:

```
                                test replications elapsed relative
2 extractElementsR(M, indexmatrix = ind)      100   0.084     1.00
1 extractElementsRcpp(M, indexmatrix = ind)   100   0.142     1.69
```

EDIT: The R function is defined as

```
extractElementsR <- function (M, indexmatrix, type1 = FALSE) {
  D <- nrow(M)

#  # get indexmatrix, if necessary
#  if(is.null(indexmatrix)) indexmatrix <- getindexmatrix(D, type1 = type1)$indexmatrix

  # extract wanted elements
  return (M[which(indexmatrix > 0)])
}
```

One could for example take the matrices

```
M <- matrix(rnorm(1000^2), ncol = 1000)
indexmatrix <- matrix(1, 1000, 1000)
indexmatrix[lower.tri(indexmatrix)] <- 0
```

as M and indexmatrix.

EDIT2: I commented the `else` statement in the Rcpp function and omitted the default `NULL` value in the R function as it is not important for my question. I want to improve the speed of the Rcpp function when indexmatrix is provided. However, I want to keep the default `NULL` value (and create and indexmatrix when necessary).

Comment: What is `getindexmatrix`?

Comment: It is a function constructing the indexmatrix, according to the dimension and type, if no indexmatrix is passed to the function extractElementsR(cpp). Its specifics are not important here as I want to focus on speed improvements when the index matrix is passed, while I want the function to remain having the NULL default value for the index matrix.

Comment: You could view the function getindexmatrix as the function constructing the indexmatrix as provided in the example matrices when type1 = T; and 1-indexmatrix when type1 = F. Of course with the same dimensions as M.

Comment: Actually it *is* important in the sense that your code is not runnable without it. Also, it may be another contributing factor to the slow performance of `extractElementsRcpp`. Please include this function as your example is not currently reproducible.

Comment: I explicitly mentioned I benchmarked when indexmatrix is provided, hence that part of the code is never run and it can't contribute to the performance. You can comment the `else` part in the `extractElementsRcpp` and omit the `NULL` default in the R-code without changing the intention.

Comment: I edited the original question such that the code does not depend on `getindexmatrix`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show

1. the function `extractElementR()` as well and
2. example data so that this become a *reproducible* example?

And at first blush, you are mixing Rcpp and RcppArmadillo types in order to subset with the latter.  That will create lots of copies.   We can now index with both Rcpp (and Kevin has some answers here) and RcppArmadillo (several older answers) so you could even try two different ways.

Comment: The R function, as well a simple data example is added to the question. I tried to look for answers about how to reduce the amount of copies, but it seems I'm looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks for completing the question.  I am busy with something else right now but maybe somebody else can take it from here.  One level of additional copies comes from your switching between Armadillo and Rcpp types, even in the function interface. Maybe simplify and try without `Nullable` but an arma index matrix.  Reduce your code complexity.

Comment: No problem. I'd like to keep the Null default value in the function as index matrix, which is not possible when starting with an arma index matrix. I tried to do everything in Rcpp, which would avoid a lot of copying, but could not get the subsetting to work.